# Make a custom URL and link to custom Template

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a set of categories in my WP site. I also have a "team" thing in my site. Now when a user makes a new post he selects a category and then chooses the team to which post belongs.

I have added this team selectbox using meta boxes Now i want to have a link for each team.

How can i do that??..

I though of 2 ways:

(1) - Making a template and linking it to a page called team. So its url becomes :
         site.com/team/
      And now for each team making url like
         site.com/team/team1
      I thought that 2nd url will also be served from my template. But, instead it gave not           found.

(2) - Making a custom page for each team.

Is there any other way???

Comment: Try change URL structure in /wp-admin/options-permalink.php and select "Post name" radio button to get the expected URL structure.

Comment: @balajimca I have the required permalink structure. I want to make url and its endpage

Answer (score 0):

Could create post-types, team 1, team 2, team 3. Than create a single-team1.php and use that template file to list stuff that has to do with team 1. Example:

```
<?php

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'team1', 
        '' => '',
        '' => '',
        '' => '',
    );

    $team_one_stuff = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $team_one_stuff -> have_posts() ) : while ( $team_one_stuff->have_posts() ) : $team_one_stuff -> the_post();

?>

    <!-- Do WP stuff here -->

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

    Wow, nothing assigned to team 1... o__O

<?php endif; ?>
```

You could pimp-up the metaboxes you use for team by using [ACF](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com). Realy easy to create new metaboxes for certain pages or post-types whith that plugin.

Hope it helps.

/Paul